# Zipping specified files by names in Python

Tags: python, zip

I want to zip the files that I have sorted myself previously and added to a list their names. All I want now is that to zip the files that exist in my list file, and specify the directory of the final zip file to where it is needed to be saved (path).

Code:

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import zipfile
from zipfile import ZipFile

def listingtheFiles():
    global onlyfiles
    onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir("C:\\Users\\woosa\\Desktop\\MainFolder") if isfile(join("C:\\Users\\woosa\\Desktop\\MainFolder", f))]

def loweringAllLetter():
    global lowercasednames
    lowercasednames = []

    for i in range(len(onlyfiles)):
        loweredName = onlyfiles[i].lower()
        lowercasednames.append(loweredName)

def searchName():
    global studentName
    global specificfoldername

    studentName = str(input("İsim:"))

    specificfoldername = []

    for names in lowercasednames:
        if studentName in names:
            specificfoldername.append(names)

    print(specificfoldername)

def zippingFiles():
    #CODE IS NEEDED HERE:
    pass

listingtheFiles()
loweringAllLetter()
searchName()
```

Comment: To clarify, are you trying to zip a handful of files together? or zip individual files

Comment: zip individual files, like the ones that I will specify